# Minimum of a function of matrices

Tags: matrices

I want to find the minimum to the following problem:

$$
\min_{X} \|f(X)\|_F \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $X$ is a rectangular matrix, and $f$ is a function of it, involving other matrices, the norm is Frobenius norm.

I want to know if the solution of problem \eqref{1} is equivalent to the following problem:
$$
\min_{X} \|f(X) A\|_F \tag{2}
$$
where $A$ is a rectangular matrix.

Are the two problems equivalent? if not, are there some properties on $A$ so that they become equivalent?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Equivalent in what sense?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay in the sense that the minimum is the same, i.e they have the same solution

Comment: X_{optimal} for problem (1) is the same for problem (2)

Comment: They are trivially equivalent if $AA^T=I$.